# understand asp.net clientid generation for $ and _ (underscore) differences

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, .net

am working on a production support ASP.Net project and project was upgraded to 4.5 from 2.0 (.net framework) now. Problem is, this project contains lot of hardcoding in finding asp.net control in both javascript and csharp file

eg. ctl00$MainContent$txtName or ctl00_MainContent_txtName

am just confused, why they were used $ (cs file) and _ (javascript in asp.net designer) for the same control and it's working.

Please assist me when we need to use $ and _(underscore) to fetch element in a rendered page.it's useful for me to justify while working on this project.

Comment: That name is generated by asp.net to prevent collisions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453989/how-to-name-and-find-dynamically-created-webcontrols-in-c-sharp might be of use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the **Id** property of the asp.net Controls, additionally there is a Property called **ClientIDMode** for every control, and there is a set of value to be used in there, i would suggest you to use **ClientIDMode=Static**, like this all your controls will be rendered with the Id you just set them instead to have all this ctl00_MainContent_txtName stuff. You can also set this **ClientIDMode** for all you web form instead to do it for every control.

Here is the Microsoft documentation: [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access the server control from javascript instead of using the whole name you can do this:

```
var a = document.getElementById("<%= YourControlID.ClientID %>");
```

This will generate the relevant id by itself and you wont have to bother about $ and _